# Creating topic in kafka_2.12-2.2.0 causes “Timed out waiting for a node assignment” error

Tags: apache-kafka

Does anyone know how to fix this error when creating a new topic in Kafka?

```
➜  kafka_2.12-2.2.0 bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic user-tracking
Error while executing topic command : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
[2019-07-14 13:01:35,094] ERROR java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:163)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:134)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicService.createTopic$(TopicCommand.scala:129)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$AdminClientTopicService.createTopic(TopicCommand.scala:157)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:60)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

I have Java and Maven installed:

```
➜  kafka_2.12-2.2.0 mvn --v
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383a37b1f9e9b3bc3df5050n29c8cff9f215291; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
Maven home: /Users/User1/Development/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
➜  kafka_2.12-2.2.0
```

I have started zookeeper:
`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

I have started server-1:
`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server-1.properties`

I ensured server-1.properties is listening to port 9093:
`listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093`

I then tried to create a topic:
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic user-tracking`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have configured `listeners` incorrectly. The following should do the trick:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
```

Comment: this worked for me